# Is there a lightweight way to snap windows in Lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu, lxde

I'm looking for a lightweight way to snap windows in Lubuntu. It's possible to install `compiz`, but doing so will make the system far less lightweight. Are there any alternatives or workarounds?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Using a lightweight window manager

You could use the lightweight compositing manager used by XFCE called *xfwm4*

[image]

This will give you basic windows snap.

N.B. if you dont like the default "change workspace when dragging a window off the screen" capability then untick the very last option shown in the picture.

## Getting Tiling to work

However - if you want the "tiling-snap" of compiz you will need to get your coding-hands dirty because this is work-in-progress.

According to [this article](http://notanothersheep.com/XFCE4WindowTiling) - there is a potential [patch](http://aur.archlinux.org/packages/xfwm4-tiling/xfwm4-tiling.tar.gz) available to enable windows tiling (aka windows snap) for the xfwm4 compositing manager.

Through the [following Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103456/automatically-size-windows-using-xfce-like-in-gnome/103560#103560) I have packaged this tiling patch into my PPA - instructions for installation can be found in the linked answer.

There is a [great you-tube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sAc6vc93jxc) video showing this in action.

---

## How to use xfwm4 in lubuntu/lxde

To use *xfwm4* as your compositing manager instead of OpenBox.

In Desktop Settings - Advanced options change the window manager to `xfwm4`

[image]

Now in terminal:

```
cd ~/.config/lxsession
mkdir Lubuntu
cp LXDE/* Lubuntu/
```

Install the compositing manager:

```
sudo apt-get install xfwm4-themes
```

Logout and login for the xfwm4 compositing manager to take effect.

Change the style via `xfwm4-settings`

Comment: To add xfwm4-settings to your preferences menu you can follow this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/295737/how-do-i-add-xfwm4-settings-to-the-preferences-windows-in-lubuntu

Comment: This is a non-solution. People are using Lubuntu if they want LXDE and OpenBox, so installing XFCE4 is out of question. Remember that questions and their answers should be as generic as possible and not tailored to single users.

Comment: @andyn - I've no idea what you are referring to with the latter part of your statement.  If you wish to discuss, pop into the general chatroom.

Comment: FWIW: Update to @fossfreedom's answer for `Lubuntu 15.10`. You need to add the `xfwm4` entry into the following config screen: `Application Menu` -> `Preferences` -> `Default applications for LXSession` -> `Core Applications` tab -> `Windows Manager` entry: type in `xfwm4`.

Comment: @ATutorMe I've asked a very related question, but I'm not sure if this fix is up to date. Could you check it out? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1192585/auto-resizing-and-snapping-windows-feature-on-lubuntu-lxde

Comment: @fossfreedom  I've asked a very related question, but I'm not sure if this fix is up to date. Could you check it out? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1192585/auto-resizing-and-snapping-windows-feature-on-lubuntu-lxde

Answer (score 16):

<kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>arrow</kbd>

<kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> split the screen horizontally.

<kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd> split it vertically.

Comment: this doesn't work by default on lubuntu 20.10

Answer (score 10):

I personally use [quicktile](https://github.com/ssokolow/quicktile).

It allows you to snap windows in different regions of your screen based on keyboard inputs (e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> to get the window to the top-left corner). It can be run as daemon on any X11-based desktop and only requires python as a dependency.

As far as I can tel, it does not have a drag-and-snap function, but your question did not seem restricted to mouse-only behaviour.

Answer (score 5):

[This](http://crunchbanglinux.org/forums/topic/13968/aero-snap-in-openbox/) thread on crunchbang forum talks about getting `aero-snap` feature by tweaking `openbox`. If you want to look into tile, cascade and expose like feature in lightweight environment you may look into [this](http://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?pid=25268). Although posted in xfce forum it may be useful for other windowmanagers as it uses `xwininfo`, `wmctrl` and `xdotool`. so you need to install 
`x11-utils`, `xdotool` and `wmctrl` and bind some keyboard action to the given script. I have been using it in xfce and it works OK for me. If you need compositing as well, try [cairo-compmgr](http://cairo-compmgr.tuxfamily.org/), which will give you transparency, expose like functionality and many others without replacing your window manager. In order to install:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:shnatsel/cairo-compmg
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cairo-compmgr
```

And just start it OR add to your startup script.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you check out [OpenSnap](http://lubuntublog.blogspot.de/p/opensnap.html).

2020 UPDATE: https://lubuntu.me/tip-opensnap/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: **OpenSnap was a good hint.  His link is down. Here is an official one:** https://lubuntu.me/tip-opensnap/