# Is it possible to place windows with keyboard shortcuts in Xfce?

Tags: shortcut-keys, window-manager, xfce, xubuntu

With Compiz in Unity, I could press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd> to place a window on the right-half of the screen, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> to place it on the left half, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd> to place it in the top left quarter of the screen, and so on.

Is there something similar in Xfce on Xubuntu?

Comment: You could use [wmctrl](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/wmctrl/) and easily keybind commands like `wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b remove,maximized_vert,maximized_horz && wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -e 0,0,0,500,500`. See [man wmctrl](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/wmctrl.1.html).

Comment: Is this a duplicate of this? http://askubuntu.com/questions/103456/automatically-size-windows-using-xfce-like-in-gnome ... or are you using 12.10 which should have tiling built into the WM.

Comment: I use 12.04 LTS

Comment: [wmctrl](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/wmctrl.1.html) looks great but [how do i resize the active window to 50 percent?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53150/how-do-i-resize-the-active-window-to-50-percent)

Comment: @rubo77, If you're familiar with bash scripts, http://sprunge.us/VjYL. But you might as well consider installing 12.10 since fossfreedom says it's built in.

Comment: thanks, that worked. (I don't want to upgrade, cause I am administering customers with 12.04 LTS until next LTS-Release). I added your script [there](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53150/how-do-i-resize-the-active-window-to-50-percent)

Comment: @rubo77, about your panel issue, did you try with Y=24 instead of Y=0 (considering your panel's height is 24 pixels) ?

Comment: thx, that fixed that too. I optimized the script solution [there](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53150/how-do-i-resize-the-active-window-to-50-percent)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

i prefer using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> to move the window into the left half of the screen and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> the right half.

- store [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/53228/20661) script as `/usr/local/sbin/window-left` and `/usr/local/sbin/window-right`
- in your [Settings Manager](https://askubuntu.com/a/165087/34298) you can add a new entry in xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts: `/commands/custom/<Alt>d`, `String` and `/usr/local/sbin/window-left`
- in your [Settings Manager](https://askubuntu.com/a/165087/34298) you can add a new entry in xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts: `/commands/custom/<Shift><Alt>d`, `String` and `/usr/local/sbin/window-right`

[image: new entry for shortcut to move window into left half of the screen]

(You can choose the best shortcut Keys, that fit for you using `<Alt>, <Shift>, <Control> and <Super>`)

Comment: If your shortcuts isn't working, remember to make them executable. 
 chmod +x /usr/local/sbin/window-left
 chmod +x /usr/local/sbin/window-right

Comment: This answer is out of date with newer XFCE versions (see this question/answer for how to do it natively: http://askubuntu.com/questions/210231/xubuntu-12-10-window-tiling-shortcuts)

Answer (score 7):

These actions already exist for the Window Manager of XFCE/Xubuntu, it's a matter of binding them to proper keys!

You can do this through the GUI. Just go to `Settings`, `Window Manager`, and click the `Shortcuts` tab. The actions you are looking for are named `Tile window to the left`, `Tile window to the top-right`, etc.

Comment: Even if late vote but this is the correct answer (at least in my xubuntu environment 16.04)

Comment: This is definitely the correct answer as of 16.06

Comment: Recently installed XFCE Debian 9. Funny thing is, I tried this but it does not work on the window manager settings itsefl, so I thought it was not a solution. After reading your answer I tried again, it works on most everything except the window manager :).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem after switching away from Compiz, as I have not found a real solution and I did not want to use single scripts, I forked a project, which nearly had the features which I needed.

You can find it under: https://github.com/gillesB/azulejo

It is not perfect yet, multiple screen support is missing, but I use it everyday. It should also be usable in other desktop environments as it is based on EWMH (1). For example I used it for a while with Mate and I tested it shortly with Cinnamon.

1) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EWMH

Comment: File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 76, in require_version
    raise ValueError('Namespace %s not available' % namespace)

Comment: I created an issue for that problem on GitHub. I will look after it in the near future. (https://github.com/gillesB/azulejo/issues/9)

Comment: The problem occurs if the dependencies are not installed. You can find the needed packages here: https://github.com/gillesB/azulejo