# XFCE Full Window Tile

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, tiling

I'm using XFCE 4.10 (Xubuntu 13.10), when I drag any window to the top of the screen, it gets tiled to half desktop, like this:

[image]

Also when I drag the window to the left or right, it doesn't stick vertically.

How can I have it maximize windows when tiling them on the top or bottom of the screen?

Comment: It's a feature, not a bug. That's how the developers wanted it and how they implemented it. There is no way to fix it unless you can persuade, bribe or blackmail them to do it for you. Of course you can disable it, see Salt's answer.

Comment: @aquaherd I don't want to disable it. Is there a way to change its behaviour? Maybe editing some configuration file?

Comment: I don't know if there's a way to do so while dragging to edges yet, but a workaround I've used is setting keyboard shortcuts for "Maximize", "Tile window to the left", and "Tile window to the right" under Settings > Window Manager > Keyboard.

Comment: This seems to have changed to default behaviour now with xfce 4.12 in 15.04 - https://bugzilla.xfce.org/show_bug.cgi?id=9927 aka bug is now fixed ;)

Answer (score 2):

"How can I solve it?" If I take your meaning sir, you are displeased by two default Window Manager settings. One can be found in Settings Manager -> Window Manager Tweaks -> Accessibility -> Automatically tile windows when moving toward the screen edge. For the other, perhaps you are thinking of Settings Manager -> Window Manager -> Advanced -> Wrap workspaces when dragging a window off the screen.

Comment: Did you read the question? When I drag the window on the top of the desktop, it doesn't fit the desktop, it fits just a half of it. So the tiling works but it just doesn't make the window fit the desktop, which is pretty an useless feature. And this happens with the _Settings Manager -> Window Manager Tweaks -> Accessibility -> Automatically tile windows when moving toward the screen edge_ toggled on. And the setting to wrap workspaces doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is in the (question in the) following link:
[xubuntu 12.10 window tiling shortcuts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/210231/xubuntu-12-10-window-tiling-shortcuts)

"To align a window to left/right/top/bottom half of a screen with mouse you should go to 'settings editor' -> 'xfwm4' and uncheck 'wrap_windows' property. Now you can drag window beyond the edge of the screen to tile it."

Comment: Doesn't work. As I said, **I'm able to tile windows**. But **I don't want** windows to take half screen when tiling them top or bottom, I want them to maximize when tiling them on top or bottom of the screen.

Comment: I agree with @BackSlash, the current xfce defaults are ridiculous. Does anybody have a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

The property you want is called 'maximize_window_key' in your xfce4-keyboard-shortcut settings. The default is - `<Alt>F10`.