# How to tile window on the corners in Xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, shortcut-keys, xfce, window-manager

After I realized that Unity is overstretching my graphics card and my CPU, I decided to remain to Ubuntu by switching to Xubuntu. Xubuntu is must faster, but I am now trying to reproduce the handy window handling behaviour with keyboard shortcuts, as it used to be done by Compiz in Unity.

[xubuntu 12.10 window tiling shortcuts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/210231/xubuntu-12-10-window-tiling-shortcuts) explains how to enable this functionality for side-by-side or top-to-bottom tiling. But in order to fit 4 windows on the screen, I still **need a shortcut for moving a window on the screen corner**, like `Alt+Ctrl+Num` used to be for Unity.

Comment: Did you try this http://askubuntu.com/questions/207685/is-it-possible-to-place-windows-with-keyboard-shortcuts-in-xfce ?

Comment: Yes. I have already linked to that on my original question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I set a keybinding to resize a window to half its size, in a chosen direction?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/576427/can-i-set-a-keybinding-to-resize-a-window-to-half-its-size-in-a-chosen-directio)

Answer (score 1):

I have this corner tiling option available in Xubuntu 14.04 with Xfce 4.12. Go to Window Manager > Keyboard. There you will see options for *Tile window to the top-left* etc.