# App suggestion to handle window tiling on a large display

Tags: display

I just upgraded my dual-monitor setup to a 50 inch 4k ultrahd display and I am looking for some solutions to handling tiled windows on it. I know windows has a few third-party programs that help with easily adjusting windows in a grid layout (gridly, etc). Is there any linux alternatives short of replacing my default DE? I currently use gnome3 on ubuntu.

Comment: would this be a suggestion? You can repeatedly resize to 1/2, 1/4, 1/8 to get the window layout you need. http://askubuntu.com/a/576694/72216 Should work on Gnome as well, but have to test.

Comment: I just tested it, the XFCE version works on Gnome, but would need some tweaking for Gnome specifically. Let me know if it's what you like and I'll edit it for Gnome.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the settings manager, onboard settings, window?

On my system I can check dock to screen edge, which seems to work.
[image]