# How to tile window by mouse to left/right edge in Xfce (like in Unity)?

Tags: xubuntu, xfce

I don't interesting in shortcuts. I want to do it by dragging windows.

Comment: what version of xubuntu are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 14.04

Answer (score 10):

Making the assumption you are using xubuntu 14.04 there are a couple of GUI options you could explore:

Using the Window Manager - Advanced options you can disable the scrolling of workspaces when dragging the window left and right.  This will tile the window on these borders.

[image]

Alternatively if you dont use workspaces, by simply reducing the workspaces to 1 then windows will automatically snap to left and right

[image]

If you are using xubuntu 12.04 then tiling is not a built in option for the window manager.  See the first linked question for a workaround for this

If it still does not work for you, you might need to enable "Automatically tile windows when moving toward the screen edge" in Window Manager Tweaks > Accessibility.  See the second linked question for details.

---

Linked Questions:

- [Automatically size windows using Xfce like in gnome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103456/automatically-size-windows-using-xfce-like-in-gnome)
- [xfce4 "tiling windows when moving to screen edge" not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/848304/xfce4-tiling-windows-when-moving-to-screen-edge-not-working)

Comment: Works on Linux Mint 18.1 XFCE