# Lubuntu with only Ubuntu's workspace/tiling features

Tags: lubuntu, workspaces, distro-recommendation

I searched around for a long time but found nothing.  I am moving from Ubuntu to Lubuntu.  Everything is great (I am okay with the bland style) except for three features that I use regularly in Ubuntu.

1) <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> / <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> zooms out to see an overview of the current workspace and all the workspaces respectively.

2) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>num</kbd> which puts the current application in a specific portion of the workspace.

3) Snap to edge of workspace.

How would I get those three features onto Lubuntu?  Would that cancel out the benefit of Lubuntu, so I should just stick with Ubuntu (or any distro you can recommend)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Googling around gave me this answers:**

1. Is a feature of Unity or Compiz I doubt you can get same with LXDE/Openbox.
2. Check this [document](http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Bindings) for default key bindings available and way of changing them.
3. This [guide](http://www.jasoncavett.com/2012/05/better-aero-snap-with-openbox.html) may help you.

---

**AU Linked Question**

- [Is there a lightweight way to snap windows in Lubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73536/is-there-a-lightweight-way-to-snap-windows-in-lubuntu/73798#73798)

Comment: You can not get the specific Unity features, but most of them are because of Compiz (notably the ones requested by the OP), so Install Compiz and use it instead of Openbox.