# How do I add xfwm4-settings to the Preferences windows in Lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu, lxde, preferences, xfwm4

So I am running Lubuntu 12.10 and I just switched my windows manager to xfwm4 following the instructions here:

[Is there a lightweight way to snap windows in Lubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73536/is-there-a-lightweight-way-to-snap-windows-in-lubuntu/73798#73798)

I was wondering, how do I add xfwm4-settings to the preferences panel?

I found this page:
http://www.h-bomb.nl/2012/08/10/xfwm4-window-manager-lubuntu/

that showed how to add the Windows Manager Tweaks preference box but I'm still not sure how to add the settings preference.

Comment: Could you please explain why you found it necessary or advantageous to switch your window manager to xfwm4?

Comment: I wanted to be able to use the "snap to other windows" feature while still having a lightweight window manager.

Comment: That's why I asked. Openbox, by default, does have a lot of "poor man's aerosnap". The first sentence in the [less voted answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/114432/25656) in the link you provided covers that. And that's what I use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it was a similar file:

```
xfce-wm-settings.desktop
```

I removed the following line:

```
OnlyShowIn=XFCE;
```

and it appeared.

Comment: Where could I find this configuration file?