# What is the terminlogy for moving ("snapping") windows?

Tags: lubuntu

Lubuntu use to have "snap" functionality built-in per https://askubuntu.com/a/354200/545291

I would like to be able to "snap" (move) lubuntu 22.04 windows to either the left or right half of the monitor as described by the MacOS application Rectangle:  https://rectangleapp.com/

[image]

Windows 11 also has similar ["snapping" functionality](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/snap-your-windows-885a9b1e-a983-a3b1-16cd-c531795e6241).

What is the name for this capability in LINUX world?

Does lubuntu 22.04 have said capability built-in?

lubuntu shortcuts: https://manual.lubuntu.me/lts/F/keyboard_shortcuts.html

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking, but Lubuntu uses the LXQt desktop (GUI), which is WM *agnostic*, with Lubuntu using `openbox` as its WM (*window manager*) which thus handles windows. The programmed keyboard shortcuts can be seen [here in the manual](https://manual.lubuntu.me/lts/F/keyboard_shortcuts.html) being a mix of LXQt & for windows Openbox configs.  FYI:  LXQt knows about windows, but its windows have no borders & cannot move around; the WM provides the borders of windows, allows resizing/movement & gives windows close/minimize/rollup/maximize etc buttons.

Comment: @guiverc  Thank you for the response.  I have update the post with examples to clarify sought functionality.

Comment: There are many posts about this eg. https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/how-to-snap-windows/247 , and sometimes this is best achieved by swapping out `openbox` with another WM (easily done as [LXQt being *agnostic* makes it easy](https://manual.lubuntu.me/lts/3/3.2/3.2.13/session_settings.html).  The default *shortcuts* Lubuntu provide were created & tested with `openbox` in mind (*and what you want isn't easiest in openbox!*), so you may need to re-add the existing shortcuts coded for *openbox* if you use them. Don't forget Lubuntu aims to be **light**, and each extra feature takes away from this

Comment: @guiverc  I think you are indicating that LINUX refers to said functionality as a `Windows Manager` and that default can be changed to [any of the 8 WMs in this article](https://itsfoss.com/best-window-managers/)?  Any suggestions / recommendations are appreciated

Comment: Wow... most of the WMs require a significant time investment to setup / configure.

Comment: Only 8?   I've QA-tested Lubuntu using at least 7, and none of those listed in your provided article (*I really like IceWM, but I use it alone and not with LXQt; my testing uses others*). I'm using Lubuntu *mantic* right now, and my WM is `xfwm4` which is the default for a Debian LXQt install actually (ie. Xfce's WM). Sorry I can't advise or recommend; for Lubuntu QA-purposes I avoid changing my setup from default unless I have to (I'm impacted by some of `openbox` bugs thus my using `xfwm4`, but my *unaltered* configs allow me to switch back to `openbox` logout/login & test when required)

Comment: Another FYI:   We had a Lubuntu *dev* who aimed at working on this feature for 23.10 (*which likely would have allowed jammy/22.04 users to benefit too, if they were using LXQt 1.3 via backports*), alas other events in life took away his time and he felt *forced to resign* from the project

Answer (score 2):

Lubuntu uses the LXQt desktop (GUI), which is WM agnostic, with Lubuntu using `openbox` as its WM (*Window Manager*) which thus handles windows.

The programmed keyboard shortcuts can be [seen here in the manual](https://manual.lubuntu.me/lts/F/keyboard_shortcuts.html) being a mix of LXQt & for windows *Openbox* configs.

FYI: LXQt knows about windows, but its windows have no borders & cannot move around; the WM provides the borders of windows, allows resizing/movement & gives windows close/minimize/rollup/maximize etc buttons.

There are many posts about this eg. https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/how-to-snap-windows/247 , and sometimes this is best achieved by swapping out `openbox` with another WM ([*easily done as LXQt being agnostic makes it easy*](https://manual.lubuntu.me/lts/3/3.2/3.2.13/session_settings.html)).

The default shortcuts Lubuntu provide were created & tested with `openbox` in mind (*and what you want isn't easiest in openbox!*), so you may need to swap out openbox & then re-add the existing shortcuts coded for `openbox` if you use them in the format of your chosen WM.

Don't forget Lubuntu aims to be ***light***, and each extra feature takes away from this

FYI: there are *many* WMs you can use, I somewhat regularly test with 5 if we have an issue that maybe related to `openbox` and have tested at least 7 with Lubuntu/LXQt.

Another FYI:   We had a Lubuntu *dev* who aimed at working on this feature for 23.10 (*which likely would have allowed *jammy*/22.04 users to benefit too, if they were using LXQt 1.3 via backports*), alas other events in life took away his time and he felt *forced to resign* from the project. We're a small team, so the task wasn't picked up.

Comment: Very insightful answer.  I realize now that I should have indicated that if I could simply press SUPER+ RIGHT_ARROW to snap the window to the right half of the screen, that would be enough (along with SUPER+LEFT_ARROW).   Thank you for taking the time to share your insight